# Desandro's new masonry example giving me "Uncaught ReferenceError: container is not defined"

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-masonry, slicknav

I've been designing a freelance web design portfolio for my company. Which is static on s3 @ http://drootech.com.s3-website-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/dtindex.html

Originally I had been customizing the older version of masonry (using jQuery/Javascript to create a responsive portfolio) with the ability to filter out various content types by category (design, engineering, etc.)

It seems to be working fine, however I am getting an error in my console "Uncaught ReferenceError: container is not defined"

Here's the code:

```
$(function (){
var columns = 3,
    setColumns = function() { columns = $( window ).width() > 640 ? 3 : $(window).width() > 320 ? 2 : 1; };

setColumns();
$(window).resize(setColumns);
    var $container = $('#portfoliocontainer');
    $container.imagesLoaded(function(){
      var msnry = new Masonry( container, {
        itemSelector : '.item',
    columnWidth:  function( containerWidth ) { return containerWidth / columns;
    }
      });
});
```

});

Any kind of help or light on the situation would be greatly appreciated, I'm not sure why I'm getting the error.

**EDIT** I fixed the error with the following code.

```
// responsive masonry function
$(function msnry(){
var columns = 3,
setColumns = function() { columns = $( window ).width() > 640 ? 3 : $(window).width() >    320 ? 2 : 1; };
setColumns();
$(window).resize(setColumns);

    // layout Masonry again after all images have loaded
    var $container = $('#portfoliocontainer').masonry();
    var msnry;
    $container.imagesLoaded( function(){
    var container = document.querySelector('#portfoliocontent')
    msnry = new Masonry( container, {
    itemSelector : '.item',
    columnWidth:  function( containerWidth ) { return containerWidth / columns;}
      });
});
$('.expandi').click(function(){
    $('.expand').slideDown('fast');
    $(this).siblings('ul').toggle();
});
$('.engineeringiC').click(function(){
    if($('div.item').hasClass('designshwr')){
    masonry.hide(($this));
    $container.masonry('reloadItems');
}
});
});
    $("#seemore").click(function (){
        //$(this).animate(function(){
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $("#mrkting").offset().top - 85
                 }, 2000);
        //});
    });
    $("#home").click(function (){
        //$(this).animate(function(){
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $(".masthead").offset().top - 85
                 }, 2000);
        //});
    });
$("#info").click(function (){
        //$(this).animate(function(){
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $("#mrkting").offset().top - 85
                 }, 2000);
        //});
    });
    $("#portfolio").click(function (){
        //$(this).animate(function(){
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $("#portfolioo").offset().top - 85
                 }, 2000);
        //});
    });
    $("#menui").click(function (){
        //$(this).animate(function(){
            $('#navbar').addClass('slicknav');
            $('#navbar').slideDown('fast');
        //});
    });
    $("#socialmedia").click(function (){
            $("#myModal").modal('show');
    });
  $(window).scroll(function(){
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1080) {
  $('#contentnav').fadeIn('fast');
  $('#contentnav').addClass('dynamicnav');
}
if ($(this).scrollTop() > 400) {
   $('#navbar').slideUp('fast');
   $('#navbarm').slideDown('fast');
} if ($(this).scrollTop() < 1080) {
   $('#contentnav').removeClass('dynamicnav');
}
```

});

What I'm attempting to do with the code above when you click the div engineeringiC is hide everything that has the class "designshwr".

```
$('.engineeringiC').click(function(){
    if($('div.item').hasClass('designshwr')){
    masonry.hide(($this));
    $container.masonry('reloadItems');
}
});
```

But I'm having a really difficult time making it work. Any thoughts, or suggestions? P.S. Ignore the expandi function that's something I need to rewrite.

Comment: So please point to the line where you're defining `containter` variable that is used here:  `var msnry = new Masonry( container, `? (that's what interpreter explicitly says to you)

Comment: You're right, I wasn't defining the container variable. However, since I fixed that now there's another problem! This is now my issue: masonry appears to layout fine, but on the code I edited in above it doesn't reload the items or seem to do anything when I click it. My browser actually blocks the javascript from running too.